# How to show error msg in ContentNote?

Tags: trigger, lightning-experience, notes, contentnote, contentdocumentlink

I want to show error msg whenever notes get created without attaching to any records. As trigger on ContentNote is not available I've written Trigger on ContentDocumentLink, but I am not able to show error msg on New Note screen.

Code:

```
trigger ContentDocumentLinkTrigger on ContentDocumentLink (after insert) {
    System.debug('ContentDocumentLink:');
    String strLinkedEntityId;
    for(ContentDocumentLink nt : trigger.New){
        strLinkedEntityId = nt.LinkedEntityId+'';
        if(strLinkedEntityId.startsWith('005')){
            //nt.ContentDocumentId.addError('Notes can not be save as private, attach it to any record');
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Try hooking onto the ContentDocument object to trigger your validation logic - if there are no links to other records, no ContentDocumentLinks will be created hence your logic never fires.  That said, I havent been able to hook any error messages into the content note UI either! Good luck.

Comment: I am not clear about the relationship between ContentDocument & ContentNote objects, I followed the following salesforce developer guide doc which is also not showing any relationship between mentioned object.

would u pls help me in understanding how ContentDocument is related to ContentNote?

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_contentnote.htm